# Sudden change: closing lid turns off external monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, power-management

I have a MacBook Pro M1 with two external monitors, one on the HDMI and one on a Thunderbolt port. This setup has worked well for quite a long time now.

Prior to this morning, I would plug in the laptop, open the lid and all three displays would wake up. I'd log in and then close the lid. The external monitors stayed on if the power supply was connected.

Now when I close the lid all the monitors turn off. I don't know what changed.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a connected mouse and keyboard?

Comment: @Ezekiel  Yes. Wireless, attached through a Thunderbolt dongle. Logitech K270.